# Mind-numbing voltages

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, voltage

What effects would come of extreme voltages? In the range of $10^{20}$ volts (paired with 1 amp of current) and beyond? What would happen to objects coming in contact with such a powerful electric field?

Comment: This is too broad. The effects on what? What are imagining this voltage being applied to?

Comment: nonphysicists want to know but sometimes they don't know how to ask about what they don't know. Physicists have a hard time forgiving this

Comment: @lurscher It's just hard to objectively answer a question that isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

The physically relevant quantity is not volt, but the gradient of voltage, which is electric field

At about $10^{18}$ volts per metre, the [Schwinger limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_limit) is expected to kick in and introduce nonlinearities in the response of the vacuum. Above this limit, electric fields become masked by a mechanism similar to [color confinement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_confinement) inside hadrons and mesons, where the potential energy is strong enough to make electron-positron creation energetically favourable